# How to post HTML FORM Data to a http link given to you by a client using php

Tags: php

Hi guys im quite newbie on coding but i want to ask How to post HTML FORM Data to a http link given to you by a client thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html post automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578836/html-post-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a .html file as below:

```
<html>
    <form method="post" action="urclientlink">
        <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
        <input type="text" name="submitButton" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Please elaborate on your question for a better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is no different from submitting form data to a page on your own site. You simply amend the form's action attribute:

```
<form action="http://another-server.com/another-page">
```

You also need to be sure you get the right METHOD: e.g. `GET` or `POST`:

```
<form action="http://another-server.com/another-page" method="GET">
```

You will need to check with the client to see which page and method they need.